# How do I install a ceiling fan with remote control when there are separate switches for the fan and light?

Tags: electrical

Our house was wired for ceiling fans. Currently there is only a light there. I purchased a Casablanca isotope 5000 series ceiling fan with wall transmitter.  So, we have 2 wall switches.  One for the light and the other for the fan. Which one should I use for the transmitter?

Answer (score 1):

Always turn off the power. The wall transmitter will work in either switch spot, as long the transmitter is light and fan. The other switch would just be a dummy switch. You can get a new two gang switch cover from the HI Store if you do not have one.
[image]